# Mysql select based on result from query

Tags: mysql

I have this table -> table_1

[image: following table]

and this data in it

[image: follwoing_table_data]

and this -> table_2

[image: post_table]

and this data in it 
[image: posts_table_data]

i want to select from this table based on class_key 
i mean like select all posts that there table_1.class_key =  table2_class_key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple `JOIN`, e.g.:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.class_key = t2.class_key;
```

[Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) MySQL's documentation on `JOIN`.